# Unable to connect to wired connection

Tags: networking, deepin

I'm using Deepin OS since a few weeks now and I'm unable to connect to a raspberry pi 4. It's working fine using the wlan or using another device but not using a wired connection on deepin os. I also checked other threads on this topic but none of them worked.

I also checked my drivers,

set managed = true on /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf,

added

```
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

to my /etc/network/interfaces
I tried same with `allow-hotplug enp4s0` instead of auto enp4s0

Output of `lspci | grep Ethernet`:
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)

Output of `uname -a`:
Linux jankrb-PC 5.10.18-amd64-desktop #1 SMP Mon Mar 1 17:09:41 CST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output of `cat /sys/class/net/enp4s0/device/power/control`:
on

Using `modprobe r8169` also didn't worked

Output of `sudo ethtool enp4s0`:

```
Settings for enp4s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

A friend of mine also installed deepin os onto his notebook and got the same problem, so it seems to be not a hardware problem as well.

Any ideas about this problem?
Thanks in advice

Comment: Hi @JanKrb what's the wired connection connected to, what's your confirmation of "not working"? Can you ping anything (local gateway?  google - 8.8.8.8)?  Have you got an IP address configured? (bypassed DHCP?)?

Comment: Hey, as soon as deepin tries to establish a connection, a notification is coming saying "Unable to connect to wired connection 1. Please check your cable or router.". Also in the connection menu, I always see wired connection 1 loading, pinging is also not possible. I can ping anything I want to except the raspberry pi I want to connect to. I set ```iface enp4s0 inet dhcp``` to enable dhcp.

Comment: Is this a direct connection? Or is there a router or switch in-between the notebook and RasbPi?

Comment: It's a direct connection. It's directly from the laptop's lan port to the raspi's lan port.

Comment: Hmm - I'd have thought dhcp is going to be a problem if you don't have something serving up addresses.  If it's hard-wired you'll have to statically configure both ends - AND this is a different network to however else you are connecting to places ...